# Update error: The following packages have unmet dependencies

Tags: server, updates, 22.04, dependencies, cockpit

I am trying to update my Ubuntu Server via Cockpit interface and it says this:

[image: image with error]

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  libmailutils6: Depends: mailutils-common (= 1:3.7-2.1) but 1:3.14-1 is to be installed 
  qemu-system-x86: Breaks: qemu-kvm
  libtss2-tcti-cmd0: Breaks: libtss2-esys0 (< 3.0.1-2) but 2.3.2-1ubuntu0.20.04.1 is to be installed  
  libtss2-tcti-device: Breaks: libtss2-esys0 (< 3.0.1-2) but 2.3.2-1ubuntu0.20.04.1 is to be installed
  libtss2-tcti-swtpm0: Breaks: libtss2-esys0 (< 3.0.1-2) but 2.3.2-1ubuntu0.20.04.1 is to be installed
  libtss2-mu0: Breaks: libtss2-esys0 (< 3.0.1-2) but 2.3.2-1ubuntu0.20.04.1 is to be installed 
  libgc1c2: Conflicts: libgcl but 1:8.0.6-1.1build1 is to be installed 
  fuse3: Breaks: fuse
  libtss2-tcti-mssim: Breaks: libtss2-esys0 (< 3.0.1-2) but 2.3.2-1ubuntu0.20.04.1 is to be installed  
  libtss2-sys1: Breaks: libtss2-esys0 (< 3.0.1-2) but 2.3.2-1ubuntu0.20.04.1 is to be installed  
  libgc1: Conflicts: libgc1c2 but 1:7.6.4-0.4ubuntul is to be installed
  libtss2-esys-3.0.2-0: Breaks: libtss2-esys0 (< 3.0.2-1) but 2.3.2-1ubuntu0.20.04.1 is to be installed  
  qemu-kvm: Depends: qemu-system-x86 (= 1:4.2-3ubuntu6.27) but 1:6.2+dfsg-2ubuntu6.12 is to be installed
```

Is this something bad? How can I fix this to have nice clean updating?

Result of cat /etc/apt/sources.list

```
# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy main restricted
# deb-src http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy universe
# deb-src http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal universe
deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates universe
# deb-src http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy multiverse
# deb-src http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal multiverse
deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse


deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security main restricted
# deb-src http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main restricted
deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security universe
# deb-src http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security universe
deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security multiverse
# deb-src http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security multiverse
```

EDIT 27.08.2023, 9:25 - Thank you very much guys. I run the sudo apt clean and sudo apt dist-upgrade and now in my cockpit interface I see that everything is up to de with a green mark. :) Thank you very much!

Comment: Run `sudo apt clean` and then `sudo apt update` and then `sudo apt dist-upgrade` and if it still complains, then try running `sudo apt -f install` and then run `sudo apt install libmailutils8 libtss2-esys-3.0.2-0 libgc1 qemu-system-x86` or at least `sudo apt install libmailutils8 libtss2-esys-3.0.2-0 libgc1` and try to uninstall `sudo apt uninstall qemu-kvm libtss2-esys0` and maybe `sudo apt uninstall fuse` **but pay attention and do not accept the changes (Y) for any of these if it will uninstall multiple packages that you need or do not want to uninstall from the system**!!!

Comment: If the uninstall goes well, then try the install, dist-upgrade, and/or `sudo apt -f install` and not necessarily in that order. Once you can do `sudo apt dist-upgrade` and `sudo apt -f install` without an error, you'll know the problem is fixed. Please report any errors by updating the result in your question, thanks.

Comment: As for fuse, it may be up to you. For now, it's complaining that fuse3 is incompatible with fuse. This might not be an issue after you run `sudo apt clean` and then `sudo apt update` but if it's still an issue after that, then you may have to make a choice of which one to keep, either fuse3 or fuse but I guess that would depend on which packages you have installed that depend on either one. So maybe try uninstalling one of them like `sudo apt --dry-run uninstall fuse`  and see if any other packages would be uninstalled, and then do the same for fuse3 `sudo apt --dry-run uninstall fuse3`.

Comment: I updated my question (IDK if I need to comment for you guys to see to), but thank you very much. After sudo apt clean and sudo apt update and sudo apt dist-upgrade in my cockpit interface now I see green mark with everything is up to date. So I didn't do the other commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, run:

```
sudo apt clean
sudo apt update
```

and then run:

```
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

It looks like the system still has updates cached from when the system was 20.04. Running `sudo apt clean` and then `sudo apt update` should refresh the cache.

Comment: Thank you, once again. Yes I did the do-release-upgrade just yesterday. from 20.04 to 22.04.